# Load balancer not working with http2 - AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, load-balancing, http2

I have a network load balancer setup on EC2 and everything works fine, though I'd like to enable http2 to get better performance and scores from auditing tools (eg. lighthouse).

My setup is Nginx on Ubuntu, the load balancer only has 2 instances to point to.

When I setup the listener to use http2, it doesn't work even though nginx and everything on the instances is setup properly. Is it because I'm using certificate manager and that there's no way for the balancer to use the certificate if it's installed through there?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If someone comes across this, I ended up being able to solve the issue recently.

My problem was that I needed to install a self-issued certificate on both of my EC2 instances. That enables the back-and-forth between the load balancer to be secured and, in turn, it allows the load balancer to reply with the http2 headers signaling that it's available. For some reason, I thought that this was already configured, but it wasn't.

Now everything works fine!

Comment: `http2.createSecureServer(options, app)` is a considerable assumption in my opinion. There are many reason why you could safely create a no secure server off http2